# SQL Comma Delimit Problem

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a small problem. I am getting this error, and I would appreciate if anyone could help me out! All I am trying to do is a comma delimited list.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TypeID Varchar(250)

SELECT
    @TypeID = COALESCE(@TypeID +',' ,'') + TypeID 
FROM
    Related

RETURN @TypeID
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '8,' to data type int.

Does anyone know how to fix, please? I've tried `CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TypeID)` but this doesn't seem to make any difference!

Answer (score 4):

Is the field TypeId in the related table an integer?   You would need to cast the database field to a varchar for your code to work

```
Select @typeId = coalesce(@typeId+',','') + cast(typeId as varchar(20))
from related
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct that you need to `CAST` the int to `varchar` but the other problem is you are using `RETURN @TypeID`.

The [return statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778.aspx) expects an integer (usually used to indicate success/failure **not** for data) and can not be used with strings. You need to use an `OUTPUT` parameter or a `SELECT` statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) `TypeId` as a varchar:

```
DECLARE @TypeID Varchar(250)

SELECT
    @TypeID = COALESCE(@TypeID + ',' , '') + CAST(TypeID As varchar(20))
FROM
    Related

RETURN @TypeID
```

Another method would be to use string concactination:

```
Declare @TypeId varchar(250)
Select @TypeId = ''

Select @TypeId = @TypeId + ', ' + CAST(TypeID As varchar(20))
From Related
```

Comment: Hi, Still same error :( "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '8,11,17' to data type int."

Comment: Hmm, not sure what could be happening. Try generating a string instead of using `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

DECLARE @TypeID Varchar(250)

SET @TypeID=''

SELECT  @TypeID = COALESCE(@TypeID + ',' , '') + CAST(TypeID As varchar(20)) FROM Related

SELECT STUFF(@TypeID , 1, 1, '')